# Convert JSON Array of Objects to List<String>

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, json-simple

I'm having a piece of that selecting data in JSON and I want to convert it to Java ArrayList.

```
String q = "SELECT attributes FROM common_attr_test";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(q);
preparedStatement.execute();
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    valueAttributes = rs.getString("attributes");
} 

JSONObject obj=(JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(valueAttributes); 
JSONArray arrOne=(JSONArray)obj.get("1"); 
System.out.println(arrOne);
```

From the code, I get the below result:

```
[{"entry":"1","count":1},{"entry":"2","count":1},{"entry":"3","count":1}]
```

I try to code using

```
ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();

if (arrOne != null) { 
    int len = arrOne.size();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
        listOne.add(arrOne.get(i).toString());
    } 
} 
System.out.println(arrOne);
System.out.println("\nlistOne:"+listOne);
```

and getting the result :

```
[{"entry":"2","count":3}]
```

My question is how am I going to put the result into an ArrayList in Java like below :

```
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)]
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: I'm using json-simple.

Comment: try using gson or jackson library, that'll make things a lot easier for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need go through your `JSONArray`, cast each element into a `JSONObject` and extract the `entry` and `count` values from each one, then make a string out of them and add to your list:

```
if (arrOne != null) {
    JSONObject entryCountJson;
    String entry, count;
    for (Object o : arrOne) {
        entryCountJson = (JSONObject) o;
        entry = String.valueOf(entryCountJson.get("entry"));
        count = String.valueOf(entryCountJson.get("count"));
        listOne.add("(" + entry + "," + count + ")");
    }
}
System.out.println("arrOne: "+arrOne);
System.out.println("listOne: "+listOne);
```

This outputs:

```
arrOne: [{"entry":"1","count":1},{"entry":"2","count":1},{"entry":"3","count":1}]
listOne: [(1,1), (2,1), (3,1)]
```